# How do i make array of id in nested json

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I convert this json into an array of `file_id` only

```
 {
        "file_id": 1,
        "name": "r1",
        "file_parent_id": null,
        "subfolder": [
            {
                "file_id": 3,
                "name": "r1.1",
                "file_parent_id": 1,
                "subfolder": [
                    {
                        "file_id": 7,
                        "name": "r1.1.1",
                        "file_parent_id": 3,
                        "subfolder": [
                            {
                                "file_id": 9,
                                "name": "r1.1.1.1",
                                "file_parent_id": 7
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "file_id": 5,
                "name": "r1.2",
                "file_parent_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
```

to this

```
$arrayid=[1,3,7,9,5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_decode` with `array_walk_recursive`

```
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
$a   = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v,$k) use(&$a){
 if($k == 'file_id') $a[] = $v;
});
```

Demo : https://3v4l.org/5CcZt

Comment: Nice solution lad